# What's the Equivalent in TFS 2012 Build of a TFS 2008 Exec Task?

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I had a TFS 2008 structure with a complex set of extra Tasks in XML files to do things like run custom EXEs with parameters for uploading to S3 buckets, etc.

Now with a fresh install of TFS 2012, and the WF build bits, I see no way to easily translate and add these tasks.

What is the right way to add the capability to the XAML definition to run some local EXEs after successful build?

Comment: Note that WF was introduced to TFS Build in TFS 2010. The equivalent of the tasks is to create custom workflow activities. They're quite simple for the sort of thing you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Exec tasks are commonly found within msbuild project files.  Have you tried incorporating these tasks into your solution's source?

Here is the reference for [the MSBuild Exec task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x8zx72cd.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use InvokeProcess Activity. See properties for details (executable finame, arguments...).